# Windows programs's system calls

Tags: windows, operating-system, system-calls

Is it possible to log all system calls made by a specified program? For example I have a GUI tool, wrapping some command-line based tools. I need to know how does it start command-line programs, what file manipulations is it doing. Actually I want to repeat this actions in integration purposes.

**UPD:** [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) did this job

CreatePorocessA API call - shows external programs and parameters selected process is calling

Comment: Sysinternal has provide a set of tools may fit your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These things can be handy in case...

http://j00ru.vexillium.org/?p=1010

http://billauer.co.il/blog/2010/07/strace-ltrace-win32-api-dll/

Second one helped me in some other scenario.. Let me know whether it works for you or not...!!